# Does StartCopyFromBlob replace destination?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

What is the behavior of the `StartCopyFromBlob` method, when the destination blob already exists? Is the destination replaced?

I could not find an answer for this, even in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any existing destination blob will be overwritten. However, you can change this behavior by using an AccessCondition.

For more information on Copy Blob, please refer to the [REST API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894037.aspx).

Comment: I found the condition you told. For others who come here: `If-None-Match` with value `*` will not copy the blob if destination already exists, returning status `412 (Precondition Failed)`.